# TealScript - How to work with uint64 and uint256 and how to do conversions between them?

Tags: algorand, tealscript

TealScript - How to work with uint64 and uint256 and how to do conversions between them?

Hi, what is the best practice to work with bigints in the tealscript?

for example:

how to properly write this method?

```
  @abi.readonly
  multiplier(param1: uint64, param2: uint64,param3: uint64) : uint256{
    return param1*param2*param3; 
  }
```

currently the build fails with the error

```
Error: Type mismatch: got uint64 expected uint256
TEALScript can not process ReturnStatement at contracts\contract.algo.ts:463:4
    contracts\contract.algo.ts:464: return param1 * param2 * param3;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be explicit with the return type.

```
 @abi.readonly
  multiplier(param1: uint64, param2: uint64, param3: uint64): uint256 {
    const p1 = param1 as uint256;
    const p2 = param2 as uint256;
    const p3 = param3 as uint256;
    return p1 * p2 * p3;
  }
```